# Image downloading is not working in android

Tags: android, image

I am trying to download the image from the URL http://dbh_cache.s3.amazonaws.com/19445/34173cb38f07f89ddbebc2ac9128303f-33b64a2ed0f1ff4750f183b4f2a161b8.png

It seem the domain of the URL contains underscore which results in image download failure. Please let me know if i am correct

Comment: I am going to tell you the magic spell,  say with me **If some image is opening in browser by passing a URL, then You can download it too.**

Comment: post your code please

Comment: I have used the Universal image loader SDK to download the images and when i change the image URL to something else(not having any underscore) its working fine.

Comment: If I click on the image link you provided, I get an error message, that this bucket does not exist. I guess your image url is simply wrong.

Comment: @Christopher i have used the dummy url here due to privacy issue

Comment: Do you need any kind of authorization to access this url?

Comment: No there is not authorization is required for this also its working fine in iOS

Answer (score 0):

```
public class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> {


        ImageView img;
        Bitmap bitmap;
        Context con;
        ProgressDialog pDialog;
    public LoadImage(Context updateProfileActivity,
                ImageView profileImageView) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        con   = updateProfileActivity;  
        img = profileImageView;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(con);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Image ....");
        pDialog.show();

    }
     protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... args) {
         try {
               bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(args[0]).getContent());

        } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap image) {

         if(image != null){
         img.setImageBitmap(image);
         pDialog.dismiss();

         }else{

         pDialog.dismiss();
       //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image Does Not exist or Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Its also not working. I also tried with the NetworkImageLoader class so i can save the image for future use